# Unable to reproduce CVE-2018-7212 in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, windows, security, sinatra, exploit

I'm trying to reproduce CVE-2018-7212, a Sinatra path traversal vulnerability, for a class demonstration. I've installed Sinatra v2.0.0rc2, conjured up a very simple Sinatra website, and have it running locally.

I'm trying to execute this path traversal to get another file from my computer, say an image file that is two directories above my website. I can't seem to figure it out in browser or on the command line, if anyone knows how to do this and could explain it that'd be awesome!

I've tried various combinations of periods, slashes, and backslashes in both my browser and via curl on the command line. Everything I try returns "Bad Request" or gives me a 404.

[CVE-2018-7212](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-7212/)

[Sinatra Patch Code](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/1379/files/d17aa95f5056c52daf5d7c3170fbfd831dc96381)

[Another listing of the CVE](https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-RUBY-SINATRA-22017)

The example given in the third link doesn't quite make sense to me as the CVE and its patch seem to say that backslash escaping was exploitable, which would make sense for a Windows host, not forward slashes and periods. Further, this CVE only pertained to Windows hosts, and the example path given us a UNIX path. And it doesn't work, anyways.

I'm expecting to be able to run a proper curl command to take advantage of this CVE and download a file from another directory on my computer.

Thanks!

Comment: Well you do not expect them to give the direct commands to Hack , Do you ? I think the text does goes on to refer that by using a malicious zip archive that holds path traversal filenames it might be possible to do partial information disclosure. May be you need to do some research in this area.

Comment: Of course not; that's why I've been trying to come up with an exploitable backslash command, as I mentioned. The listed command does not concur with the description of the CVE. However I've had no luck.

The ZipSlip vulnerability is a way to further exploit a path-traversal vulnerability in order to create files or possibly enable RCE, this is not what I'm trying to do. I'm merely trying to pull files from outside the website's directory.